# Error message when using ggcorrplot() and cor_pmat()

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggcorrplot

I have trouble with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)
data(USArrests)
correlation_matrix <- round(cor(USArrests),1)
corrp.mat <- cor_pmat(USArrests)
ggcorrplot(correlation_matrix, hc.order =TRUE, type ="lower", 
           p.mat = corrp.mat)
```

When I run the code, execution stops at ggcorrplot(...) and I get this error:

> "Error in Math.data.frame(x = list(Assault = c(0.0695, 1.36e-07,
> 2.6e-12,  :    non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame: rowname"

I tried to run the code in an online R runner and it worked, but in RStudio it doesn´t.

I have no clue whats going on, has somebody an idea?

Comment: I don't get any errors when I run your code. Try with clean environment?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Indeed unloading the unneccessary packages helped.  The package "rstatix"  seemed to interfere with the cor_pmat() command.

Comment: @sev perhaps post that as an answer if you think it will be useful to other people

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Quinten for your suggestion. Unloading the unnecessary packages helped. The package `rstatix` seemed to interfere with the `cor_pmat()` command.